# How use inside common provider $http in Angular 1.4?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to use common provider and in angular app config function set data in provider.

```
.provider('userData', function() {
    var authUser = {};
    return {
        checkUser: function() {
            // wish to able use $http here for request to get data from service
            // save all data into 'authUser' object
            // $get return 'authUser' object
        },
        getCookie: function(value) {
            // wish to able use $http here
        },
        $get: function() {
            // only for return object
            return authUser;
        }
    }
})

app.config(['userDataProvider', function(userDataProvider) {

    userDataProvider.checkUser();
});

.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', 'userData', '$http', function($scope, userData, $http) {
    // use inside all controllers/directives 'userData'
});
```

I try to use $http as parameter in $get function -> not working: error:

```
$get: function($http) {
     return authUser;
}
```

Also I can't find any valid example for using $http inside provider. Inside service/factory $http work fine, but I need to prepare data in provider from config function.

Comment: It seems working for me, could you check [this here](http://jsfiddle.net/97eremed/) & try to replicate a problem..

Comment: @PankajParkar but try it in config phase, when services aren't available yet

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, I must be missing something silly to understand whats happening, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7byp2wdv/) I created.

Comment: @PankajParkar look at this http://jsfiddle.net/7byp2wdv/1/ . Services aren't available at config phase

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't get anywhere that OP is asking for such thing, though thanks for clearing it up. Basically service, factory & value isn't accessible inside config phase by design, I've updated your answer with same info, Thanks :)

Comment: @PankajParkar `$http` is  a service itself

Comment: I know man.. I was confused because of this `$get: function($http) {
     return authUser;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`Service`s, `factory` & `value` aren't available at config phase by design.

You could do it in `run()`

```
app.run(['userData', function(userData) {

    userData.checkUser();
});
```